# datagridview virtual mode, update RowCount causes CellValueNeeded to fire for all rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to implement datagridview's virtual mode but when i set RowCount to some number (to show the scrollbar) the grid wants to have all rows at once, not only the displayed.

```
DataGridView grid = new ...;

grid.VirtualMode = true;
grid.CellValueNeeded += OnCellValueNeeded;
grid.RowCount = dataprovider.GetFullCount();
```

How can i tell the grid to only request the rows displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunatly this seems to be the standard behavior. i could solve it either by

```
void OnCellValueNeeded(...)
{
    if(!_active) return;
}

grid.VirtualMode = true;
grid.CellValueNeeded += OnCellValueNeeded;
_active = false;
grid.RowCount = dataprovider.GetFullCount();
_active = true;
```

or implementing IBindingList, ITypedList with complex lazy fetching in background thread

**Update:** the problem seems to be fixed now. I can not reproduce it anymore using the following:

```
static class Program
{
    private static Form form;
    private static int i;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var grid = new DataGridView
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            VirtualMode = true,
            AllowUserToAddRows = false,
            Columns =
            {
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "foo" },
                new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "bar" },
            },
        };
        grid.CellValueNeeded += OnCellValueNeeded;
        form = new Form
        {
            Controls = { grid }
        };

        //grid.RowCount = 0;
        grid.RowCount = 10000;

        Application.Run(form);
    }

    private static void OnCellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        form.Text = i.ToString();
        e.Value = "fooValue";
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have column autosize mode set to allcells

Comment: didn't make a difference, see my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404739/671619

Comment: @VisakhVA what does not work: My workaround or that it was not magically fixed on your machine?

Answer (score 6):

This is just a guess, but do you have the AutoSizeRowsMode or AutoSizeColumnsMode values set to AllCells or are any of the columns set to that either?  Try setting the resize mode to None or just DisplayedCells and see if there is still a problem.

Comment: unfortunatly `grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;` and `grid.Columns.ForEach(col => col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None)` do not change this behavior

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the same problem as I was having, but I did get very poor performance when regularly drastically changing the RowCount on a VirtualMode DataGridView.

What I noticed was that the scroll bar was changing "slowly"; i.e. it looked like it was individually removing my virtual rows (!).

Anyway, doing a `grid.Rows.Clear()` before each call to `grid.RowCount = n` drastically improved performance.

Comment: my problem is that `grid.RowCount = n` would immediatly call OnCellValueNeeded for all rows, even not displayed

Comment: That doesn't answer the original question but solves my performance problem. Thanks!

Comment: I’m also seeing this same issue. I am using the `RowCount=0` solution because setting `RowCount` takes 10+ seconds without it when going from e.g. `RowCount=10000` to `RowCount=2`, but note that when using this solution one must also manually restore the selection. I wish the netfx didn’t use a loop in `RowCount.set()` for `value!=0`…

Answer (score 2):

You should set the RowCount to zero before setting the full count.

```
DataGridView grid = new ...;
grid.VirtualMode = true;
grid.CellValueNeeded += OnCellValueNeeded;
grid.RowCount = 0;
grid.RowCount = dataprovider.GetFullCount();
```

Comment: my problem is that `grid.RowCount = dataprovider.GetFullCount()` would immediatly call OnCellValueNeeded for all rows, even not displayed. Try setting RowCount to 1000 with one column and have `Thread.Sleep(100); e.Value = "Something;"` in `OnCellValueNeeded`.

Comment: Setting RowCount to zero before setting another count prevents OnCellValueNeeded calls for all rows. Just try, it works for me.

Comment: This seems to match the suggestion from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c823a522-56f5-451b-9d5e-bdeac8833eeb/speeding-up-setting-of-datagridviewrowcount?forum=winformsdatacontrols . But no one says why this should work other than that .netfx is quirky?

Comment: Is there possibility somehow to filter by specific column/s when grid is in virtual Mode? Lets Say i płace text for some columns to show only matching record and grid to show Such matching record nevertheless for all data not only for those shown current in grid

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I tried the solution of setting an active flag like you did, and I also tried the solution of setting the RowCount to 0 (or grid.Rows.Clear()) before setting the new RowCount.

Both of these things improved performance, but neither sped it enough to be as instantaneous as I want because I am dynamically filtering the grid in real time based on input from a search box.

I found two other solutions:

1) Use pagination so that you don't have to set the RowCount so high to begin with.  I think this is a great solution if you are already using pagination (in which case you wouldn't be here) but an overly cumbersome one if you weren't planning on implementing it.

2) Put the call to set the RowCount in its own thread.  This is the one I'm about to attempt.  Honestly not sure how safe this one is if you're trying to edit cells while the thread is still finishing up but I guess I'll find out soon enough.

EDIT:

OK, so I tried threading it hoping that would do the trick since I read elsewhere that it really helped another guy.  It seems to be a good solution *IF* you are just going to change the value once in a while but it still hangs if you do it multiple times consecutively (which I am).  I think this is because you have to use Invoke() and the second time around it's still waiting for the first one to finish.  Can't say I totally understand what the deal is but I've decided just to live with the blank rows for now because it's SOOO much faster and less complex when I just leave them there.

Comment: there is always a delay between requesting the data and receiving the data. Responsive UI with temporaryly empty cells is the best UX i can imagine because if the data requested is not really the data wanted by the user (eg he's just scrolling) it doesnt matter

Comment: @Firo Yeah.  I just think it's incredibly stupid that when you lower the record count, it actually still tries to get values for records above the count you set before it finishes updating the count.  And what's more is, why the heck is it even trying to get values for records that aren't even displayed on screen?  I still think the DGV is one of the greatest, most awesome controls Microsoft has provided us, but they definitely could have done that part of it a little better.

Comment: How do you filter by specific columns? Could you share any code or whatever? Your filter works along all data and not only for those whcih is shown?