# Strange behaviour in CellValueNeeded

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I use in virtual mode. In testing that I created some version that behaves quite strange.

This is the method body:

```
private int i = 0;
private void dgData_CellValueNeeded(object sender, 
                         DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
        i++;
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine
                ("cell value needed call: " + e.ColumnIndex + ", " 
                  + e.RowIndex + ", "+i);

    e.Value = i;
}
```

This results in the call being called for **all** cells. when I replace `e.Value = i` with `e.Value = e.RowIndex`, only cells in view are called.

**update** I found that call `SetSelected` made the call to all cells. But still, *only* when `e.Value` is set to an arbitrary value.

How is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "only applicable cells are called"?  Are you saying that you only see your Console.WriteLine text for cells for which e.ColumnIndex is indeed 0?

Comment: I mean that in the last case, only the cells that are actually in view are called. When I do `e.Value = i`, the method is called for every cell in the grid, as defined by `RowCount` (which is something like 350,000) and `ColumnCount`.

Comment: Generally, virtual mode will only fire the CellValueNeeded event at Paint time for a given cell, so as you say, only cells that are actually in view would fire the event (normal).  But there are some cases where that's not true, like this one:  AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells  (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4d08a818-0eda-47fb-87c1-4e4e6d041fa0/datagridview-virtual-mode-invoking-cellvalueneeded-for-entire-rowcount) or this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404336/datagridview-virtual-mode-update-rowcount-causes-cellvalueneeded-to-fire-for-al)

Comment: `AutoSizeRowsMode` is set to `None`. Also, the behaviour changes when I change the mothod **body**.